# Aluminum plate sliding on top of aluminum work surface. They will scratch each other. What can be used to protect them and to easy the sliding?

Tags: aluminum

I am building a jig for a router table and I realized too late that using an aluminum base for the jig will scratch the router table which is also made of aluminum.
What can be used to prevent this scratching and to make the sliding smoother ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultra-High Molecular Weight (UHMW) plastic is available as self-adhesive tape in various widths and thicknesses. It slides well over most smooth surfaces.

Depending on how stuff your jig is, you might not have to cover the entire bottom.

Oh -- and you probably want to ease (round over) the corners of the jig so they don't scratch, catch, or otherwise cause trouble.

Comment: Hmm I knew about UHMW but not about HDPE https://www.curbellplastics.com/Research-Solutions/Plastic-Properties/HDPE-vs-UHMW
However I can't find anything like 1/16" or thinner and self adhesive on Amazon Canada
The size I need is 12"x12". I can find some tape that would be 6" wide that could work

Comment: UHMW is probably what I was trying to remember; oops...

Comment: This seems to work but a little bit expensive https://www.amazon.ca/TapeCase-423-5-UHMW-Tape-5yds/dp/B00823JFAI/ref=sr_1_59?crid=23GWYBB6QCOYR&keywords=UHMW%2Btape%2B12%22&qid=1672897688&sprefix=uhmw%2Btape%2B12%2B%2Caps%2C75&sr=8-59&th=1

Comment: I might need to install just two 1"-2" wide strips as for my Incra sled -that will add an 1/32 layer that my plate will float on

Comment: Or three if the middle needs support. Or whatever. Or redesign the jig...

Comment: I can't redesign the jig. Need a surface that does not bend under toggle clamps sitting on it and it is thin -this is the best solution I could come up. MDF or plywood 1/4" thin will bend